# Athena row_number performance optimization

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-athena, row-number

I'm running a query against the large table and I'm trying to improve the performance.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2 ORDER BY COL3, COL4) AS POSITION,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2, COL3 ORDER BY COL3, COL4) AS POSITION_IN_TYPE,
       *
FROM   TARGET_TABLE
;
```

As the **TARGET_TABLE** has about 1 billion rows, it caused the resource error.
Is there any way to optimize this query?

Much appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Usually it is optimized using indexes, do you use indexes?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Athena. Does Athena provide indexes as well?

Comment: I see, there was tag postgresql , so I thought you use Athena PostgreSQL connector.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-partitioning-and-bucketing.html

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. I would try either partitioning or bucketing. Thanks!

Comment: @dkssud no, there is no indexes in Athena.

Answer (score -1):

Is your goal to later filter the query based on the result of your ROW_NUMBER() statements? You may benefit from filtering it in this query and the SQL execution plan might be able to use that to run your query efficiently.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Maybe this is a comment. If not, please do the answer without questions.

So, If your goal is...